# C# loading the main form after successful login

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008

I have two forms namely Login and Main Form. I want that on successful log in, the log in page should close and the main form should load. But the problem that I was facing was whenever I enter invalid username and password, the main form still shows up.

I am accepting login message(Login Successfull Or Failed) as a string from SQL Server 2008 database

I tried using the following codes

1. **Code:**

   ```
   public Form1()
   {
        FrmLogin frm = new FrmLogin();
        frm.ShowDialog();
        InitializeComponent();

   }
   ```
2. **Code:**

   ```
   static void Main()
   {
       Application.EnableVisualStyles();
       Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
       FrmLogin frm = new FrmLogin();
       if (frm.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
       {
           Application.Run(new Form1());
       }
       else
       {
           Application.Exit();
       }
   }
   ```

**Login Form Button Code:**

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection("File Name=E:\\Vivek\\License Manager\\License Manager\\login.udl");
    try
    {
        conn.Open();
        OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("checkuser",conn);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        OleDbParameter p1=new OleDbParameter("userid",username.Text);
        OleDbParameter p2 = new OleDbParameter("password",password.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.Add(p1);
        cmd.Parameters.Add(p2);
        var returnParameter = cmd.Parameters.Add("@ReturnVal",OleDbType.VarChar,50);
        returnParameter.Direction = ParameterDirection.ReturnValue;
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        // Retrieve the return value
        string result = returnParameter.Value.ToString();
        MessageBox.Show(result);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }     
    conn.Close();
}
```

Stored Procedure

```
ALTER proc [dbo].[usercheck]
                   (@userid varchar(20),
                     @password varchar(20))

                     as
                     begin
                     if exists(select userid,password from users where userid=@userid and password=@password)
                     return 0
                     else 
                     return 1
                     end
```

But unfortunately none of the above codes seem to work. I found the above code snippets from questions asked by others here but they are not working for me.

Can anyone help me to rectify this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are doing it wrong,

1.) This is the Constructor for the `Form1` and this code is executed whenever the form is created, so you are displaying your `FrmLogin` form as soon as you show your `Form1`.

```
public Form1()
{
    FrmLogin frm = new FrmLogin();
    frm.ShowDialog();
    InitializeComponent();
}
```

2.) This is the Entry Method for your Windows Form Application, this gets executed when you press `F5` to run your Project, Here you are creating `FrmLogin` and just checking if the user pressed `OK` then display `Form1`. This is the right track but you are probably not checking any credentials...

```
static void Main()
{
    Application.EnableVisualStyles();
    Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
    FrmLogin frm = new FrmLogin();
    if (frm.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        Application.Run(new Form1());
    }
    else
    {
        Application.Exit();
    }
```

### Try this:

Your `Program.cs`:

```
static void Main()
{
    Application.EnableVisualStyles();
    Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
    LogonForm form = new LogonForm();

    if (form.ShowDialog() != DialogResult.OK)
    {
        //Handle authentication failures as necessary, for example:
        Application.Exit();
    }
    else
    {
        Application.Run(new Form2());
    }
}
```

Your `LogonForm`:

```
private void Login()
{
    if (CheckCredentials())
    {
        this.DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Please enter correct credentials and try again!");
    }
}

private void BtnLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Login();
}
```

**Edit:**

If you are using SQL Server 2008 then you should use `System.Data.SqlClient` not `System.Data.OleDb`.

Here is the updated code:

```
private bool CheckCredentials()
{
    bool result = false;
    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("usercheck", conn))
    {
        conn.Open();
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@userid", username.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@password", username.Text);
        using (SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
        {
            if (reader.HasRows)
            {
                reader.Read();
                result = reader.GetBoolean(0);
            }
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Syed Thanks for replying.But I dont want to use hide method...I want that the Login form should close.So this.close() would work in place of this.hide()?

Comment: Shouldn't that `Login` method be setting the `DialogResult` to `OK` on a successful login?  The startup form is already going to be shown from the `Main` method if the login is successful so the login form should not be doing it.

Comment: @SyedFarjadZiaZaidi Thanks once again.But I am a bit confused..Wait ill update my question with the complete Login Form code

Comment: @SyedFarjadZiaZaidi I am getting please enter correct credentials and try again even after entering the correct credentials.What is to be done?

Comment: nope I am entering the correct username and password that exists in the table.

Do you want to take a look at the stored procedure?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/62578/discussion-between-user2614235-and-syed-farjad-zia-zaidi).